# How can I remove duplicates in an array of object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array which looks like this :

```
var array = 
[
    {
        key : { id : 1 , pack : "pack 1"},
        values : [
            {
                item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            },
            {
                item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to remove duplicate itemP so with a function it will look like this :

```
var array =
[
    {
        key : { id : 1 , pack : "pack 1"},
        values : [
            {
                item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            },
            {
                item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},
                itemP : null
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

When I try I always have errors. It is possible to do this?

**Update**

I try to do this :

```
  console.log(array.map(pack => 
    pack.values.map((item) => {
      var test =  JSON.stringify(item)
      var set = new Set(test)

      return Array.from(set).map((item)=> JSON.parse(item))
      }
    )

  ))
```

> Unexpected end of JSON input

I also try something will filter but it doesn't work:

```
  console.log(this.package.map(pack => pack.values.filter(
    (value, index , array) => array.itemP.indexOf(value) === index
  )))
```

Comment: Why would you make the itemP `null`? That's not the cleverest to do, with angular (anyway, please share your attempt, I'm pretty sure you've tried something)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes will all my test I have .filter is not a function or unexpected end of JSON input for the last test.

Comment: Okay, seen what you've tried, keep in mind that `Set` will not work in this way. Sets are meant to be sets of **unique** values. However, stringifying an item won't solve the issue, because **strings will always be more or less different**, in your example. The map approach also can be somewhat avoided since you just need to alter the existing object. In any case, may I still ask you **why** you want to make that property null? That doesn't really makes much sense to me, considering you're using angular. May you still share further informations about the usage?

Comment: Do you use the property name `itemP` for something? Isn't it better to have just one array for the values? Doing so, your filter approach sould work

Comment: Yes I have to use itemP I just want to have it one time in my code because It's like a parent and a lot of parent can have the same parent but I don't want to show 10 times itemP if I have 10 item which have this itemP as parent. That why I wanted to remove the object and have null as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping every key property, I suggest cloning the whole structure and setting the object value as null in the cloned one, avoiding unintentionally mutating the original structure.

```js
function nullifyDupes(array) {
  const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
  const seen = {};

  clone.forEach(pack => {
    pack.values.forEach(items => {
      for (const item in items) {
        const id = items[item].id;

        if (seen[id]) items[item] = null;
        else seen[id] = true;
      }
    });
  });
  
  return clone;
}

const originalArray = [{
  key : { id : 1 , pack : "pack 1"},
  values : [{
    item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},
    itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
  },
  {
    item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},
    itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
  }]
}];

const mutatedArray = nullifyDupes(originalArray);
console.log(mutatedArray);
```

Comment: It works but if I have more than 1 entry in original Array it doesn't work it removes also the duplicate item in other key.
const originalArray = [{ key : { id : 1 , pack : "pack 1"}, values : [{item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}},{item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}}]},{key : { id : 2 , pack : "pack 2"},values : [{item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}},{item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}}]}];

Comment: You can move down the `const seen = {};` to the first loop line right after `clone.forEach(pack => {` . The `seen` object would be "cleared" for each pack doing this, avoiding the case you've commented.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using map

1. Loop array using map
2. Use nameArr to check duplicate and assigning null value
3. Loop values array and check the name in nameArr using indexOf and assign null

```js
var array = [
    {
        key : { id : 1 , pack : "pack 1"},
        values : [
            {
                item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            },
            {
                item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            }
        ]
    }
]


console.log(array.map(v => {
  let nameArr = []
  v.values = v.values.map(val => {
    if(nameArr.indexOf(val.itemP.name) !== -1){
      val.itemP.name = null
    }else{
      nameArr.push(val.itemP.name)      
    }
    return val
  })
  return v
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and an object to check if its already exist. Like

```
var obj = {}
```

and loop over values

```
var values = [
            {
                item : { id : 1 , name : "item1"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            },
            {
                item : { id : 4 , name : "item4"},
                itemP : {id : 2 , name : "itemP12"}
            }
        ]

values.map((v) => {
    if(!obj[v.itemP.id + '-' + v.itemP.name]) { 
     obj[v.itemP.id + '-' + v.itemP.name] = true; 
     return v;
    }
    return { item : v.item }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array elements to array objects which don't include your duplicates using `.map()`. For each iteration of `.map()` you can again use `.map()` for your inner values array to convert it into an array of objects such that the duplicates are converted to `null`. Here I have kept a `seen` object which keeps track of the properties seen and their stringified values. By looping over all the properties in your object (using `for...of`), you can work out whether or not the key-value pair has been seen before by using the `seen` object.

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't just work with one property (ie not just `itemP`), but it will work with any other duplicating key-value pairs.

See example below:

```js
const array = [{key:{id:1,pack:"pack 1"},values:[{item:{id:1,name:"item1"},itemP:{id:2,name:"itemP12"}},{item:{id:4,name:"item4"},itemP:{id:2,name:"itemP12"}}]}];

const seen = {};
const res = array.map(obj => {
 obj.values = obj.values.map(vobj => {
   for (let p in vobj) {
     vobj[p] = seen[p] === JSON.stringify(vobj[p]) ? null : vobj[p];
     seen[p] = seen[p] || JSON.stringify(vobj[p]);
   }
   return vobj;
 });
 return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

For an approach which just removed `itemP` from all object in accross your array you can use:

```js
const array = [{key:{id:1,pack:"pack 1"},values:[{item:{id:1,name:"item1"},itemP:{id:2,name:"itemP12"}},{item:{id:4,name:"item4"},itemP:{id:2,name:"itemP12"}}]}];

let itemP = "";
const res = array.map(obj => {
  obj.values = obj.values.map(vobj => {
    vobj.itemP = itemP ? null : vobj.itemP;
    if('itemP' in vobj) {
      itemP = itemP || JSON.stringify(vobj.itemP);
    }
    
    return vobj;
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Just an issue if I have an other object in **array** it doesn't work for the other which have a duplicate itemP.

Comment: @user10863293 I've edited my code a little. Does it work now?

Comment: It works more but it also remove item which have no itemP at base.

Comment: @user10863293 Ok, I'll fix that, give me a few min

Comment: @user10863293 Ok, I've edited my answer (the 2nd cope snippet should be what you're after)

Comment: ^^' Now I have not null in an item which have no itemP but for the other object in **array** it remove also all the itemP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196053/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-user10863293).